How to get value from paramterised enum in Scala
I'm trying to add values from enums together and I can't find how to extract the parameterised value.
enum Stats:
    case MaximumHealth(x: Float)
    case HealthRegen(x: Float)

def stuff: Float =
    val s1 = Stats.MaximumHealth(20)
    val s2 = Stats.MaximumHealth(10)
    val sum = s1.value + s2.value // does not work; expected value of 30 (Float)

How do I get to add the 20 and 10 together?

Move x to the enum level

You can create a new function say getStatAsFloat that takes in a parameter of type Stats and pattern matches against it to get the Float value. Here's how you can achieve this:
enum Stats:
  case MaximumHealth(x: Float)
  case HealthRegen(x: Float)

def getStatAsFloat(s: Stats): Float =
  s match
    case Stats.MaximumHealth(x) => x
    case Stats.HealthRegen(x) => x

def stuff: Float =
  val s1 = Stats.MaximumHealth(20)
  val s2 = Stats.MaximumHealth(10)
  val sum = getStatAsFloat(s1) + getStatAsFloat(s2)
  sum

stuff => res0: Float = 30.0


With scala 3, you can add arguments in enum.
You can also add fields and methods if you need.
enum Stats(val value: Float):
  case MaximumHealth(x: Float) extends Stats(x)
  case HealthRegen(x: Float) extends Stats(x)
  
  def +(other : Stats) : Float =
    this.value + other.value

val s1 = Stats.MaximumHealth(10.5)
val s2 = Stats.HealthRegen(20.2)
s1.value + s2.value // > 30.7
s1 + s2 // > 30.7

More on enums in scala 3 : https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/enums/enums.html
